# Error Meshing with ToElementMesh (ToElementMesh: Cannot set region holes.) for certain objects

Tags: import, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I have had a problem properly meshing certain .obj files, where others are meshed successfully.

Here is an example of a successfully meshed .obj:

[image: Success]

Whereas, using the code at the bottom which includes the imported problematic .obj, this error (shown at bottom of the image) is produced:

[image: Success]

Both methods of producing the mesh for these two examples are the same and only differ in their geometry. Is there anything that can be done?

Best to all.

````
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

R = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/499qd6zwu4who1e/round9.obj?dl=1"];
RegionDimension[R];
Imp = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
RegionDimension[Imp];
Volume[Imp];

M = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0.0072}], Imp]

r = RegionDifference[
  RegionDifference[RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {2, 2, 1}], M],
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.9}, {2, 2, 1}]], Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {2, 2, -0.9}]]
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"]
```
````

Comment: The message is about a region hole, but you do not show code that produces that message.

Comment: @user21 Weird. I copied and pasted the exact code I presented above and tried to run it and it produced the exact error I showed in image 2? It doesn't show that error for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives some clues as to why it does not work:

```
FindMeshDefects[r]
```

Here is a different approach for this geometry:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]

R = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/499qd6zwu4who1e/round9.obj?dl=1"];
s1 = OpenCascadeShape[ToBoundaryMesh[R]];
s2 = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[
   OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0.0072}]], s1];
s3 = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[
   OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {2, 2, 1}]], s2];
s4 = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[s3, 
   OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.9}, {2, 2, 1}]]];
s5 = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[s4, 
   OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, -1}, {2, 2, -0.9}]]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[s5];
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't think to specify a requirement when initially making this post. I am trying perform `NDSolveValue` over this mesh, and it appears that the output form of `bmesh` is not a BoundaryMeshRegion, but a member of ElementMesh. Is there a way to convert the `bmesh` to a BoundaryMeshRegion?

Comment: I am trying to solve: `pol = -1;
v0=4000
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[
    V[x, y, z] == -pol*
      V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
   DirichletCondition[
    V[x, y, z] == 
     pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 
       2)], DirichletCondition[
    V[x, y, z] == 
     0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
   DirichletCondition[
    V[x, y, z] == 
     0, (-0.5 <= z <= -0.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)]}, 
  V, {x, y, z} \[Element] bmesh]`

Comment: If you want to do FEM forget about `MeshRegion` and `BoundaryMeshRegion` as the FEM internally uses ElementMesh anyways. You need to convert the boundary element mesh (bmesh) to a full mesh (with ToElementMesh) and give that to `NDSolve`. Search for `ToElementMesh` in the documentation, there are plenty reference, tutorial and examples.

Comment: Thank you. I just failed to remove the ["Wireframe"] when I tried using ToElementMesh of bmesh.